# How to use local list as an input parameter for function

Tags: c#, wpf, arraylist, datagridview, wpfdatagrid

I am working on a project for school, and having quite a time with getting it to work.

The program flow is as follows:

- 1) Load in data from text file into a data grid using a windows form https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTSkb.jpg
- 2) Using another form, select a variable from the data grid to return statistics on that column https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOhlx.jpg.

Here is the function doing all of the statistics with its struct:

```
        public struct DescriptiveStat
    {
        public double max, min, sum, avg, var, stddev;
        public string range;
    }

    public static DescriptiveStat GetDescriptiveStat(List<double> data)
    {
        DescriptiveStat result = new DescriptiveStat();
        double sum = 0, sqSum = 0, max = data[0], min = data[0];
        foreach (double x in data)
        {
            sum += x;
            sqSum += Math.Pow(x, 2);
            if (x > max)
                max = x;
            if (x < min)
                min = x;
        }
        int n = data.Count;
        result.sum = sum;
        result.max = max;
        result.min = min;
        result.avg = sum / n;
        result.var = (sqSum - n * Math.Pow(result.avg, 2)) / n;
        result.stddev = Math.Sqrt(result.var);
        return result;
    }
```

The function is set by my teacher, and cannot be changed. It must take the `List<double> data` and return result.

Currently I have it so that when I press the button "Generate" in the form "DescriptiveStat" with the single variable, it calls my function to load the data into the list to prepare it to send it to DescriptiveStat function above. Here is my code:

```
        public void GetDescriptiveStat()
    {
        List<double> data = new List<double>();
        double temp;
        data.ToArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < 94; i++)
        {
            temp = dblValues[i][0];
            data.Add(temp);
        }

        data.ToList();
        //data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    }
```

I know it is reading the data into the list correctly, but I am having a problem with using this local list as a parameter for function `DescriptiveStat GetDescriptiveStat(List<double>data)` - when I try inserting something like `double result = Mathtool.GetDescriptiveStat(data);` it gives me the error:

- Cannot implicitly convert type 'MultivariateStatistics.Mathtool.DescriptiveStat' to 'double'

Can anyone please assist with what I am doing wrong, or how I can use the list as a parameter for the function?

Thank you.

Comment: _"when I try inserting something like `double result = Mathtool.GetDescriptiveStat(data);` it gives me the error"_ -- please explain why, even though `GetDescriptiveStat(data)` returns a value of type `DescriptiveStat`, you are trying to assign that value to a variable having the type `double`. Why not just declare the variable as `DescriptiveStat result` instead?

Comment: The second method of posted code `GetDescriptiveStat()` pretty much does nothing. It returns nothing. It creates a `List of <double>` called `data`, fills the list with some data… then exits. At that point… the variable `data` that was filled with data pretty much goes out of scope when the method ends. Are you sure you don’t want to RETURN the `data` variable?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was assigning it the type double as that what I had done for another method that needed to be returned, but I realize now why I cannot do that. I will try with using `DescriptiveStat result` instead! Thank you.

Comment: @JohnG You are correct - Slaven below has posted a revised function returning the data variable, and that makes much more sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you don't have to convert your list to an array (`data.ToArray()`) and then back to a list (`data.ToList()`). Second instead of `void` let your function return `List<double>` like shown below:

```
public List<double> GetDescriptiveStat()
{
    List<double> data = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 94; i++)
    {
        data.Add(dblValues[i][0]);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Now because your function `GetDescriptiveStat()` returns a list you can send it as an input parameter into the teachers function `GetDescriptiveStat(List<double> data)`:

```
DescriptiveStat myData = GetDescriptiveStat(GetDescriptiveStat());
```

There are maybe better ways to do this but you explicitly said that the teachers function cannot be changed.

Comment: Hi Slaven! Thank you for the help. This solved my problem!